# Scala not converting Int to String

Tags: scala

In the following code, Scala is unable to convert Into to String. Why?

```
object Upper{
    def main(args:Array[String]){
        val number:Int= 1;
        val no=3.3; 
        println(args.map(_.toUpperCase())+(no+number));
    }

}
```

Error is

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
                println(args.map(_.toUpperCase())+(no+number));
                                                      ^
one error found
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to print the string "[Ljava.lang.String;@...4.3" to the screen? If so, you can just convert `no + number` to a string yourself using `toString` or `"" +`. If not, your problem is not related to the fact that the number isn't converted to a string and you need to explain what you actually want to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `args.map(_.toUpperCase())` returns an Array, not a String.
You can use `mkString` to create a String from the Array:

```
println(args.map(_.toUpperCase()).mkString(",") + (no + number))
```